# Extract a substring with a regular expression in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, substring

Instead of splitting a string, how can I regex it and extract the last substring between `\` and `]`?

Example:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\anyLongString]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way is:

```
$a = "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\anyLongString]"
$a -match '([^\\]*)]$'
$matches[1]
anyLongString
```

Answer (score 12):

Another way to do it is using fewer lines of code:

```
$a = "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\anyLongString]"
$a -Replace '^.*\\([^\\]+)]$', '$1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

```
$a = ('[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\anyLongString]' `
| Select-String -Pattern '([^\\]+)(?=])').Matches.Value
```

It uses `Select-String` to find the first match, then uses the `.Matches.Value` property to get the substring.

I prefer this because it's a single line and works even if a match is not found (unlike [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17346584/15740725)), and it's explicit and elegant, unlike [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21385810/15740725) which is more concise but seems abstruse.